# Azure data factory price in real-world: Does Unchanged Upsert is treated as One Write for Billing?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Have you dealt with [Azure data factory price](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/) in real-world for several million of records
[image: Driving te]

If I configure **Copy operation** where **Upsert** mode was selected..
**When there is no change in the row**, would Microsoft treat it as one modified entity for Billing purposes?

Any pointers with real world experience on Data Factory Billing is much appreciated. Thanks for attempting to help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ADF v2 is actually moving a data and comparing a value in case of upsert , a row operation is actually being performed and since copy activity is being executed, that means you are performing Orchestration operations which incurs cost. Hence it is charged even though there are no valid rows to upsert.

similar thread :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1015698/cost-factors-for-azure-data-factory.html